# Is a join faster than storing simple values directly in the table?

Tags: sql-server

We are building a SQL Server database that contains rows with file types. These types are going to be `pdf` in 90% of cases and `zip` in 10% of the cases. When designing this database, my first though was to use foreign keys to another table holding the types, like this:

Files

```
Id | Name   | FileTypeId
---+--------+------------
1    'f123'       1
```

FileTypes

```
Id | Name
---+------
1    'pdf'
2    'zip'
```

An advantage of this design is that it makes the Files table less cluttered and in theory it should take up less space. However this design would also require me to do a join on the `FileTypes` table every time I want to select a row from the `Files` table.

The alternative then would be to store the `FileTypes` directly in the `Files` table instead:

```
Id | Name    | FileTypeId
---+---------+-----------
1    'f123'     'pdf'
```

What design is best? What is faster? Which saves more space?

Comment: Design your database correctly, using properly normalised tables and let the database engine take care of performance - until you actually have a performance issue.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. This is premature optimisation. Design for robustness, testability, maintainability, adaptability, etc. Invariably, targeting these edge case performance scenarios yields only very small improvements, and only to code paths that only represent the minority of the runtime. Until you've identified the critical paths that Require optimization, you're wasting your time which could be spent better on almost Anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're talking about bytes of difference here, but a filetype of varchar(3) is smaller than an int - and of course a tinyint is smaller than both.

And as there is no inherent ordering of filetypes (e.g., filetype_id 1 isn't really less than filetype_id 2 in any real sense), there is no absolute benefit in using numbers to store the filetypes.

Personally, I would find a new option (Option 3) to be easier - having a *meaningful key* for filetype.

```
Id | Name    | FileTypeId
1    'f123'   'pdf'

FileTypes
Id
'pdf'
'zip'
```

Then it's clean when looking at data (you don't need to do a lookup with views etc). But you can also enforce referential integrity.

Edit: as an example of cleanliness, you may have certain processing you need to do PDFs (e.g., to remove the identifying information from them). In your code you can have one of these two

```
IF FileType_ID = 14   -- PDFs
   BEGIN
   ... 
   END

IF FileType_ID = 'pdf'
   BEGIN
   ...
   END
```

---

CAVEAT (added as an edit - I had it as a now-deleted comment that the OP has replied to (sorry))

There is one (potentially serious) limitation to this - the meaningful key has to mean what you want it to mean.

In this example, you will run into problems if the extension does *not* define the filetype but you still want to differentiate them. For example, you may have a 'cs' filetype that could be either a C# code file, or CounterStrike streamed video.

In that case, you may want to separate them into two filetypes - and then using numbers to represent them is probably the easiest/most efficient.

Comment: Huh, I didn't think about this. Yes this makes more sense actually, I really don't care about the ids to be honest.

Comment: This won't be a problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

The design which is "best" totally depends on your particular needs and use case.  Certainly, the first version is normalized and is what you would want most of the time.  The `Files` table only maintains a lightweight `FileTypeId` foreign key value which can be used to lookup in the `FileTypes` table.  However, there is a join required to bring these two tables together.

In rare cases, you might find that the following join query takes too long:

```
SELECT f.Id, f.Name, ft.Name AS FileTypeId
FROM Files f
INNER JOIN FileTypes ft
    ON ft.Id = f.FileTypeId;
```

Typically, your first line of defense would be to resort to indexing one/both tables.  But in the event that even indexing still were not fast enough, you might go with the unnormalized second version in your question.  In that case, you would be throwing away a bunch of storage space, but in return the above join query would be against a single table, and might be faster.

Comment: I see. Well in this case we can expect the database to contain around 1 milion rows in the Filetable and we are supposed to try and limit the storage space used as much as possible, so we will go with the first option.

Comment: How about inserts? Lets say a client wants to insert a pdf file. Then our API would first have to query the FileTypes table for the row that matches 'pdf' and then select its id?